# Как вывести данные MYSQL в виде таблицы?

Tags: php, mysql, html5, phpmyadmin

Всем привет! Я создал базу данных 'registration' в Mysql PHPmyAdmin и таблицу users, где хранится email и username. Код PHP:

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'registration');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result1 = $db->query($sql); 
 // В цикле перебираем все записи таблицы и выводим их
while ($row = $result1->fetch_assoc())
{
   // Оператором echo выводим на экран поля таблицы name_blog и text_blog
   echo 'username: '.$row['username'];
   echo 'email: '.$row['email'];
}
```

Он выводит данные в виде строки: username: gNikitaemail: kimp@mail.ru; username: kim, email: kimpinuk@mail.ru;username: kin, email: 123@mail; username: roman, email: vilka@mail.ru .

Подскажите, как вывести данные в виде таблицы HTML?

Comment: Использовать соответствующие html-теги: `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<td>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <html>

  <table>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>email</th>

    </tr>

   <?php 
 $host='localhost';
 $user='root';
 $password='';
 $db_name='test';
         $link=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db_name);
if(!empty($_POST)) {

  $name=$_POST['name'];
     $email=$_POST['email'];
          $query="INSERT INTO table   SET name='$name', email='$email' ";
            mysqli_query($link,$query) or die(mysqli_error($link)); 

}
 $result=mysqli_query($link,$query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
for($data=[];$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);$data[]=$row) ;
    $result='';
    foreach($data as $elem) {
        $result.='<tr>';

        $result.='<td>'.$elem['id'].'</td>';
        $result.='<td>'.$elem['name'].'</td>';
        $result.='<td>'.$elem['email'].'</td>';


        $result.='</tr>';
    }
    echo $result;


   ?>
</table>
```

Comment: $query="SELECT*FROM (название таблицы)WHERE id>0 name='$name',   email='$email' ";
сделайте вот такой запрос заместо предыдущего и делайте экспорт таблицы перед тестами , если не делали раньше.

Comment: $username=$_POST['username'];
     $email=$_POST['email'];
          $query="SELECT*FROM users WHERE id>0";
            mysqli_query($db,$query) or die(mysqli_error($db));                                                      Notice: Undefined variable: query in C:\xampp\htdocs\registration\php\index.php on line 39

Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in C:\xampp\htdocs\registration\php\index.php on line 39

Comment: почему неопределена $query?

Comment: mysqli_query($db,$query) or die(mysqli_error($db)); тут ошибка, там должен быть $link

Comment: $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'registration');     $db у меня это $link

Comment: $query неопределена потому что она находится в if'е и эта строка $result=mysqli_query($link,$query) or die(mysqli_error($link)); ее не видит. Попробуйте убрать эту строку тоже в ИФ

Comment: Я вывел за пределы ифа, все норм. Спасибо огромное!! Удачи

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]